# Kendo UI - filterable: { extra: true}

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid

I am currently evaluating Kendo UI. I had a question about Grid.

Once I make filterable: { extra: true} I get the option of using either "And" operator and "Or" operator. Is there a way to get rid of "Or" operator in UI?

Answer (score 0):

And is default value in filter and drop down list with one element looks weird so you can show whole drop down list via CSS:

```
form.k-filter-menu .k-filter-and{
    display: none;
}
```

If you want there some label with text and use filterMenuInit event to add it:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit